# anchor <a> + Link to base URL

Tags: html

If I'm on a page like

http://localhost/balibar.co/?dating=dating-articles-and-information

and I want to have anchor that links to the base URL being

http://localhost/balibar.co

Is there a way to do this without hard coding the URL?

I've tried:

```
 <a href="/"></a>
 <a href="#"></a>
```

will have a few domains use this page so I don't want to hard code the domain name if possible.

Answer (score 11):

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.google.com" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="">Google?</a>
</body>
```

That link will now go to google.com

Here is the proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wXCJ/

You use HTML's `<base>` tag to specify the base url for all elements that use the `href` attribute. Now, any tag with an `href` or `src` attribute that is empty, it will automatically go to the url you specified in the base tag by default.

Comment: Base href doesn't affect just empty hrefs. It affects anything on the page that isn't using a complet Url for href or src. Anything with an absolute or relative path in href or src will be affected by this change. This includes: a, img, style, script, etc.

Comment: @DoozerBlake Absolute paths will not affect by <base>.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the page can load fine as http://localhost/balibar.co/ then a relative path with a single dot (.) will take you to it `<a href="./"></a>` I believe you can also use a single dot by itself without the slash `<a href="."></a>`

The single dot (.) in the relative path represents the current directory.

Answer (score 6):

The HTML `<base>` tag may suit your needs.

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://www.yahoo.com/images/" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Links to http://www.yahoo.com/images/ -->
<a href=".">Top-level link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the href attribute will also affect your image and artifact urls, e.g. .  [More info here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Answer (score 4):

If you would like all URLs to be relative to that base URL, you can use HTML's [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) in your `<head>` like so:

```
<base href="http://localhost/balibar.co/">
```

Comment: You might want to add as Mark and Josh did a note that base href affects not only anchor tags, but images, styles, scripts, basically any url on the page.

Comment: I state that it affects all URLs. The spec uses very similar language. I'd find it surprising if anyway _didn't_ want (or expect) it to affect all relative URLs on the page.

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="/"></a>` only works if the host sees `balibar.co` as an index page.

Otherwise you'll have to go `<a href="/balibar.co"></a>`

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand about SEO, you are better off coding the domain name, rather than an anchor.

because you have several domain names, I would use PHP to first figure out what domain name is currently used, and then write it to the link:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>">
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't assume that the OP knows PHP / has PHP support, nice suggestion though.

Comment: How do you know the asker is using PHP?