# Create Href Anchors in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, fancybox-2

I have some links to some hidden divs that are Modal lightboxes. Within my XML I did not define the lightboxes. I simply created some conditionals that pop the lightbox up when selected.

When chrome accesses the lightbox via the links, they pop up fine within my xsl. However, Internet Explorer and Firefox do not generate absolute url's to the "#links" so the browsers are having problems reading it.

I need to transform the href links to appropriate xslt. My code is below:

```
 <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="EnableLightbox5 ='true'">
       <div class="webbuttons" id="athletics"><a class="fancybox" href="#athleticsbtn">
       <img src="images/{Button5}" /></a>
       </div></xsl:when>

       <xsl:when test="EnableLightbox5 ='false'">
       <div class="webbuttons" id="athletics">
       <a class="fancybox" href="{Page[@Name = 'Button5Link']/@URL}">
       <img src="images/{Button5}" /></a>
       </div></xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Without my anchors being elements within my XML, how would I generate an href link to my anchored divs? i.e. #athletisbtn

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

href to anchor probably need a BASE tag in the document HEAD element.

```
<base href="http://yourdomain.com/" />
```

See also SO post [anchor a + Link to base URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578620/anchor-a-link-to-base-url)

This is if you need to add the anchor to the 'false' case:

```
href="{concat(Page[@Name = 'Button5Link']/@URL, '#athleticsbtn')}"
```

Comment: Hmmm... just tried it but didn't work. I am referencing the 'true' test not the 'false' test. False works perfect but the true test is what is not linking.

Comment: Please explain when EnableLightbox5 is true or false.

Comment: The base href is the URL of the page with the athleticsbtn anchors.

Comment: ahh, i see! ok let me give it a try.

Comment: So I tried the base URL but to no luck! I'm going to tear my document apart again and see where I went wrong. Works fine in other broswers but for some reason not FF or IE.